# Mistake in "Developer Role and Gender" analysis on 2018 Developer Survey

Tags: bug, survey-2018

Reading the paragraph right below the [Developer Role and Gender graph](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#developer-profile-developer-role-and-gender) of this year's Developer Survey I feel like there is a mistake. *Ipsis litteris* it states:

> Developers who are educators or academic researchers are about 10
>   times more likely **to be men than women**, while developers who are
>   system admins or DevOps specialists are 25-30 times more likely **to
>   be men than women**.

(emphasis mine)

But looking at the chart it seems that *developers who are educators or academic researchers* are about 10 times more likely **to be women than men**.

It also makes sense to present a contrast between the roles and gender, highlighting one role that is more common for (self-identified as) men and another one more common among women, but as it stands now, 2 roles, supposedly more manly, are being presented. Does not seem right.

**TL;DR;**

[Developers who are educators or academic researchers](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/#developer-profile-developer-role-and-gender) are really 10 times more likely to be a men than woman or vice-versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's 10 times more likely to be men than women because:

> All categories have dramatically more developers who identify as men than women  but the ratio of men to women varies.

The dashed line in the chart indicates the average ratio of men to women for all jobs. It's not a line indicating that the ratio is in favor of women below it and in favor of men above it. If you look on the left hand side you can see the first line is 10x meaning none of the jobs on the chart occur at even a 1:1 ratio, much less a ratio in favor of women.

Comment: This is correct. All categories have more men than women. Disappointing and disheartening to me personally, yes, but what we are trying to communicate with that graph. To clarify just a bit, academic researchers who are also developers (i.e. such as postdocs) are 10x more likely to be men than women, and this is more representation by women than other categories.

Comment: @JuliaSilge really disappointing and to be honest, to me it's surprising. Thanks BSMP. I understood that dashed line as being the divider between men/women and women/men ratio. Even more when I saw _QA/Test developer_ under the dashed line and, from my personal experience, I know more women working as QAs/Testers than men.

Comment: Well, keep in mind that "Stack Overflow members who were willing to take the survey" isn't really a random selection of all developers, so the statistics cannot be expected to represent all jobs or positions. So by these results, we can just say a greater portion of men in whatever position took the survey than women, but we can't make any statistically significant claim about the workforce as a whole.